# Pythonのcisライブラリーがインポートできない

Tags: python

Pythonでcisをインポートする方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 0):

condaを使用している場合：

```
conda install -c conda-forge cis
```

それ以外の場合は使用:

```
python3.8 -m pip install cis
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。conda install -c conda-forge cis　で試したのですが以下のような状態で進まなくなってしまったのですが解決方法はありますか？

Comment: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /

Comment: `conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true`コンダをダウングレードしてみてください
`conda install conda=4.6.11`

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただconda install conda=4.6.11 –を行うと次のようなエラーが出て結局インストールできなかったのですが対処法はありますか?

Comment: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - -

Comment: Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

Comment: 申し訳ありませんが、condaは特定のモジュールで多くの問題を抱えています。この人は解決策を見つけたかもしれませんが、それはあなたの状況に依存します https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9367#issuecomment-555156949

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。